# Ошибка в django sqlite3 : NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_order.user_id

Tags: django, sqlite

Пытаюсь написать интарнет магазин. Хочу связать User и Order.
Это модель для заказов:

```
from django.db import models
from shop.models import Product
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                             related_name="user_orders")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

Это вьюха для заказов:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrderItem
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from cart.cart import Cart
from .tasks import order_created


def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                         product=item["product"],
                                         price=item["price"],
                                         quantity=item["quantity"])
            cart.clear()
            order_created.delay(order.id)
            return render(request,
                          "orders/created.html",
                          {"order": order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request, "orders/create.html",
                  {"cart": cart, "form": form})
```

Это форма для создания заказа:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order


class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address',
                  'postal_code', 'city']
```

Наверное здесь в форме и есть ошибка? Было бы полезно узнать что конкретно изменить/добавить нужно.

При создании заказа ругается ошибкой :

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_order.user_id
```

почему я не могу получить user_id если модели связаны через ForeignKey?

Я думал во вьюхе позже сортировать для каждого пользователя в личном кабинете список заказов по id пользователя.

```
@login_required
def account(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    my_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user)
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.all()
    return render(request, "accounts/my_acc.html",
                  {"my_orders": my_orders, "order_items": order_items})
```

Может есть другие варианты как это сделать?

Comment: Добавьте код для создания заказа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderCreateForm` не содержит поля `user`, соответственно, в момент вызова `order = form.save()` это поле модели содержит `None`, что и вызывает ошибку при сохранении данных в БД. Решить можно так:

```
order = form.save(commit=False)
order.user = request.user
order.save()
```

[Соответствующий раздел документации.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Только позаботьтесь о том, чтобы представление `order_create` вызывалось только аутентифицированными пользователями.

Comment: Спасибо, буду работать в этом направлении.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/204271)

Comment: Сработало отлично)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  Не раз "натыкался" на ваши действительно высококвалифицированные ответы и здесь и на хабре и вот снова он меня ооооочень выручил! Огромное Вам спасибо!